# Fastest way to Delete whole row based on Blank Cell

Tags: excel, vba

There are so many ways to delete a whole row based on a blank cell in specific column. What I want to know is which is the fastest way to accomplish this task in terms of Excel speed. I have a sheet with about 39,000 original rows of data which then becomes 21,000 rows after I run the code below. The issue is the chunk of code takes almost 60 seconds to return. While I know CPU and such is a factor, but lets assume all else being equal.

I am using Column A as the total count of rows and Column F as the location of blank cells. Is this the best/ fastest way to write this code?

' Finds the last row with a file numbers and removes the remaining rows

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("F2:F" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: 1) You might need to dim lastrow as Long if you have larger # of rows and 2) It seems not to remove the first row if it's empty.  Otherwise I think this should be the fastest way

Comment: Don't have time to test, or write the code, but another option would be to sort on Column F, then delete the bottom rows.

Comment: @guitarthrower -  On my PC deleting about 10k rows from 50k took 10sec. Turning off calculation/screenupdating made no difference for me. However, first sorting the data by colF rediced the delete time to 0.03 sec

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams. insightful.

Comment: @Tim Williams - What was the approximate time consumed by the sort? I should think that this factor would affect judging the efficiency of one method against the other.

Comment: @Jeeped - Yes I guess that should also be included: about 0.25sec for the sort, so about 0.3sec overall. More or less comparable to Ron's solution (but if you have any formulas or formatting to preserve then the array approach will not be applicable)

Comment: @TimWilliams That's true. I thought about the sorting/deleting method, but considered he would want to retain the original order.  If that's not the case, then sorting would be an excellent option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (wishing it would help, although take backup of your sheet before!):

```
Sub FastestBlankRowTerminator()
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(6).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this exactly what the OP did? And they are looking for a different solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

I set up a matrix of 50,000 rows x 12 columns.  In column F I placed about 25,000 blanks randomly placed.

- Read the used range into an array
- Iterate through the array and read those rows with content in column F into a results array
- Clear the original data
- write the results array

A lot of steps, but the execution time was less than one second; it would probably be faster with screenupdating false; and longer if you have more columns.

**EDIT:** Screenupdating false did not significantly decrease the execution speed, which was approximately 0.36 seconds when timed with a hi-res timer.

**EDIT2:** After reading Tim Williams comment about preserving formatting and formulas, I present a different approach.  This approach will use the Advanced Filter and, on the same made up data as above, will place the data on another worksheet minus the rows that have blanks in column F.  This does require a first row of column headers in the data; or, at least, that F1 has a unique, non-blank value.

To accomplish that process takes about 0.15 seconds.
If you also want to copy it back over the original worksheet, and delete the added worksheet, that will take about another 0.3 seconds.

Here is some code to do that, but you'd have to alter it for your own specifications:

==============================================

```
Sub DeleteBlankFRows2()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet, rTemp As Range
    Dim R As Range, rCrit As Range
    Dim I As Long
Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet5")
Set R = WS.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
Set rCrit = R.Offset(0, R.Columns.Count + 3).Resize(2, 1)
    rCrit(1) = R(1, 6)
    rCrit(2) = "<>"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets.Add
    Set wsTemp = ActiveSheet
    wsTemp.Name = "Temp"
    R.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rCrit, Cells(1, 1)
    Set rTemp = wsTemp.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
WS.Cells.Clear
rTemp.Copy WS.Cells(1, 1)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wsTemp.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

=======================================

This was my original code using VBA arrays:

===========================

```
Sub foo()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim lRows As Long

'Or may need to use a different method to include everything
Set rSrc = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
vSrc = rSrc

'how many rows to retain
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    If vSrc(I, 6) <> "" Then lRows = lRows + 1
Next I

ReDim vRes(1 To lRows, 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))
K = 0
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    If vSrc(I, 6) <> "" Then
        K = K + 1
        For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
            vRes(K, J) = vSrc(I, J)
        Next J
    End If
Next I

Cells.Clear
Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2)) = vRes

End Sub
```

Comment: How did the OPs method perform for your data?

Comment: @Degustaf He only posted a code fragment, and I did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest things I can advise that should increase performance by a noticeable amount is to turn off screen updating and automatic calculation while running this procedure.

I typically turn these items off at the initial invocation of code and turn them back on after the final one. Meaning I would have one sub to contain a series of other subs and functions that it would execute in sequence. Instead of embedding this in those subs and functions individually I just set them off, execute the main sub, and then reset them.

```
' Speed Up
application.screenupdating = false
application.calculation = xlCalculationManual

<insert code you want to improve performance on here>    

' Slow Down
application.screenupdating = true
application.calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

I ran a test myself populating column a with a rowcount up to 39000 and then every other record would have a "1" in column f.

It still takes some time but only 46 seconds on my core2duo, if I don't turn off screen updating it takes 3 minutes and 34 seconds.

```
Sub Main()
    ' Speed Up
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Begin ' Main Sub

    ' Reset
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub Begin()
    ' Sub 1
    ' Sub 2
    ' Sub 3
    Remove_Blanks
End Sub

Sub Remove_Blanks()
    Dim dA As Date, dB As Date
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer

    dA = Now

    ' Commented out to indicate they could be here but if you are executing multiple procedures then you should have it occur outside of this.
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For r = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If .Cells(r, 6) = "" Then .Rows(r).Delete
        Next r
    End With
    dB = Now

    'Commented out for same reason above
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Debug.Print "Remove_Blanks: " & Format((dB - dA), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't comment on Ron Rosenfeld's post but I can comment mine and recommend it. Utilizing Screenupdating = false and assigning the sheets data into an array and the deleting the cells in the sheet and writing the array only when column 6 <> "" took 7 seconds. Which is 38 seconds faster than my solution.